# Spring security not working with form login from UI and basic auth for rest API both

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am working with Spring boot, spring security and thymeleaf for UI. I have http form based login and http session based authentication for UI part and it's working fine. But now I have to expose some rest APIs as well for clients to consume. Now I have to provide basic auth for rest API.

**Spring Security version: 5.7.11**

Below is my security config code:

```
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
        import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
        import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
        import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
        import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
        import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
        
        @Configuration
        @EnableWebSecurity
        public class SpringSecurity {
      
            @Autowired
            private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
        
            @Bean
            public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
                return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            }
        
            @Order(1)
            @Bean
            public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                     .authorizeRequests()
                     .anyRequest()
                     .hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                     .and().httpBasic();
                
                return http.build();
            }
        
            @Bean
            @Order(2)
            public SecurityFilterChain filterChain2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/index").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/process").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/process", true).permitAll())
                .logout(logout -> logout.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll());
                return http.build();
            }
        
            @Autowired
            public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
            }
        }
```

Error I am getting while hitting any REST API:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2024-02-07T10:17:55.305+00:00",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/api/enhance-process"
}
```

**Detailed console logs:**

```
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/enhance-process
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/api/enhance-process
o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /error
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Any help is appreciated to find out the issue in this code.

Comment: please enable DEBUG logs and edit your question to include the full logs so that we can read the reason for the 403, also, you can remove your configureGlobal function, it is not needed.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I have added debug logs in the question.

Comment: `Invalid CSRF token found` there is your error, i suggest reading the CSRF chapter in the spring security docs, and also whitelisting the `/error` endpoint and read the chapter in the spring boot documentation called _error handling_ which talks about that endpoint.